# How do i stop a while loop after a certain time in C

Tags: c

How do i stop a while loop after a certain time in C, i did it in c++ and i tried converting that to c (below) but it didnt work

```
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    time_t endwait;
    time_t start;

    endwait = start + seconds ;
    while (start < endwait)
    {
        /* Do stuff while waiting */
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly about this didn't work?

Comment: You don't seem to assign any value to start...

Comment: The code you show never calculates the time.  Can you show a full example, including attempted time calculation, please?

Comment: Most likely, you should not use `time_t` and a while loop like this together. Your program will ineffectively burn away CPU and lag down the system. A professional implementation would use events and threads for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about try my test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    time_t endwait;
    time_t start = time(NULL);
    time_t seconds = 10; // end loop after this time has elapsed

    endwait = start + seconds;

    printf("start time is : %s", ctime(&start));

    while (start < endwait)
    {
        /* Do stuff while waiting */
        sleep(1);   // sleep 1s.
        start = time(NULL);
        printf("loop time is : %s", ctime(&start));
    }

    printf("end time is %s", ctime(&endwait));

    return 0;
}
```

A example outprint is :

```
wugq@SSDEV016:~/tools/test $ ./a.out
start time is : Fri Jan 17 17:12:57 2014
loop time is : Fri Jan 17 17:12:58 2014
loop time is : Fri Jan 17 17:12:59 2014
loop time is : Fri Jan 17 17:13:00 2014
loop time is : Fri Jan 17 17:13:01 2014
loop time is : Fri Jan 17 17:13:02 2014
loop time is : Fri Jan 17 17:13:03 2014
loop time is : Fri Jan 17 17:13:04 2014
loop time is : Fri Jan 17 17:13:05 2014
loop time is : Fri Jan 17 17:13:06 2014
loop time is : Fri Jan 17 17:13:07 2014
end time is Fri Jan 17 17:13:07 2014
```

Answer (score 8):

In C, there are no constructors, so `time_t start;` just declares a variable of type `time_t`. It does not set that equal to the current time. You thus need to read the current time before the loop (and assign that to starttime), and read it within the loop (or within the while condition).

Also, the loop should be

```
while ((currenttime = [code to assign time]) < endwait)
{
    ...
}
```

or neater

```
while ([code to assign time] < endwait)
{
    ...
}
```

IE look at currenttime, not starttime.

In order to read the time, you want to use `time(NULL)` (if you are using time values in seconds. So your completed program would look something like (untested):

```
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    time_t endwait;
    int seconds = 123;

    endwait = time (NULL) + seconds ;
    while (time (NULL) < endwait)
    {
        /* Do stuff while waiting */
    }
}
```

Note also that if the number of seconds is small, you might want to use the higher precision `gettimeofday`. This will prevent waiting for 1 second waiting for anything from 0 seconds to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Please give a full example. I think you have to use ***time()*** to get the approximate current time..After that you can go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on linux, you should consider (depending on your application) to use signals, check alarm function and signal (this one to define the handler, which will define the behaviour of your program once a signal is received).

You'll find details in the man pages :

```
$ man signal
...
$ man alarm
...
```