# Running loop for fixed time: Counter returns different number on every run

Tags: c

I'm trying to run a loop for a particular period of time. During that period set a counter variable and increment it by 1. The goal is to see what is the final value of the counter variable during the run. I'm hoping to get the same counter value for the same running period. Seems like it is not the case. When I'm running the same loop with the same duration, the counter variable is returning a different number every time. I'm borrowing this code from [isayme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181162/how-do-i-stop-a-while-loop-after-a-certain-time-in-c).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
   time_t endwait;
   time_t start = time(NULL);
   time_t seconds = 1; // end loop after this time has elapsed
   endwait = start + seconds;
   int counter =0;
   while (1){
        if (start < endwait){
           counter=counter+1;
           start = time(NULL);
        }
        else
           break;
   }
printf("Counter Value: %d", counter);
return 0;
}
```

output on different run:

> Counter Value: 99742750
>
> Counter Value: 30134682
>
> Counter Value: 30596672

So, my question is

1. How can I get the same counter variable for a fixed loop-time?
2. I was trying to set the variable **seconds** less than 1, but it yields 0. So, How can I set this time in fractions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What else is your computer doing while this program is running? If you examine the definition of time_t, or even search using a popular search engine for __c time_t__ what data type is it? Then figure out when the next second will have elapsed after you start your program, so it then exits.

Comment: You are not going to. First, each loop will not run for the same amount of time for the reason explained in Andrew Henle's answer. Second, even if the amount of time is the same, the number of iterations will not be because of CPU power management, cache activity, network interrupts, and a number of other unpredictable things.

Answer (score 2):

On a POSIX system  [the `time()` function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/time.html) returns time measured in seconds:

> The `time()` function shall return the value of time in seconds since the Epoch.

[Windows is similar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/time-time32-time64?view=vs-2019):

> Returns the time as seconds elapsed since midnight, January 1, 1970, or -1 in the case of an error.

The first call to `time()` in your process happens at effectively a random moment **within** a single second, and then your loop runs until the return value from `time()` changes.

As such, your loop will run some random length of time between some very small fraction of one second all the way to about a full second.  The very first call to `time()` in your loop can return a value that causes your loop to end, or your loop may run for about a full second.  Or any length of time in between.

That's assuming nothing else is running on your computer.  That can and will also change your results.